# Zend database connectivity

Tags: database, zend-framework

I used this in my UserController

require_once 'Zend/Controller/Action.php';

AND

```
public function processAction()
 {

   $params = array('host'       =>'localhost',
                'username'  =>'root',
                'password'  =>'',
                'dbname'    =>'zend'
               );

   $DB = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql($params);

   $request = $this->getRequest();
   $data = array('first_name' => $request->getParam('first_name'),
              'last_name' => $request->getParam('last_name'),
              'user_name' => $request->getParam('user_name'),
              'password' => md5($request->getParam('password'))
              );
   $DB->insert('user', $data);

   $this->view->assign('title','Registration Process');
   $this->view->assign('description','Registration succes');    

 }
```

Which displayed following error. I do not have the php.ini access.

Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Db' not found in D:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\zend-test\zend-demo\application\controllers\UserController.php on line 42

i.e. on this line

```
$params = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
     'dbname'   => 'zend'
));
```

Thanks in advance!

- Mangesh

Comment: The problem seems to be that the Zend library isn't included in php.ini include_path. Also i suggest to move the database connection to the /configs/application.ini file and in index.php should the options loaded with // Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.

Tutorial on how to setup a working Zend framework

http://usingzendframework.blogspot.com/2007/01/setting-up-zend-framework.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to include all of the Zend libraries you use - not just

```
equire_once 'Zend/Controller/Action.php';
```

Also, you need to do what Jurka specified - a much better and cleaner practice.